# How can I export certain rows from a table with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, export, backup

I'm trying to create a function where users can export their entries in our system to an sql file.

I found this page in the codeigniter documentation http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html

`$this->dbutil->backup()` is nearly what I need but I don't think I can run a query like

```
SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE user = someuser
```

using that function.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: i would take a look at the source code for that particuliar function in you codeigniter copy.  There are plenty of examples of useful functionality in codeigniter classes/helpers that isn't documented well or at all in the user guide.  If you don't need it anywhere else you can always hack it.

Comment: Wouldn't ever suggest hacking codeigniter code because you can extend it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use that function you can create a temp table with the data you need first, then run that command

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE userexport_data AS 
    (SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE user = someuser)
```

```php
$prefs = array(
    'tables'      => array('userexport_data'),
    // Other options
    );

$this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
```